Load capacity for floating cabinet
I have a floating cabinet that is built out of a b grade 9mm (3/8") ply wood.
It's 1800mmx600mmx600mm (6'x2'x2')
It doesn't have doors it has one piece of wood in the middle to make it 2 cubes of storage space.
If this is not strong enough is there any suggestions to keep it sturdy but looking like a floating shelf. I was thinking of a bracket on the inside drilled into the brick behind and attached to the bottom?
My cabinets has been up for about a month but I've not slept under it just in case, lol.
the screws are about 4cm the ones in the brick are about 6cm.
stars are were the 4cm screws are in to the wood black dots are were the 6cm screws going into to the brick wall the brown dots are were I'm planning to add dyno bolts
it will really only be storing some sheets and pillows and some empty boxes maybe a 10kg worth of cables


Welcome to WSE.  Please provide more information. 9MM is rather thin.  What are you going to place in it.  It is also important to know how the cabinet parts are attached to each other.  If they are nailed together there may be problems and short screws in such thin plywood may not adequately secure to the panels. Finally, it is unclear where the screws to the wall are repositioned (at the top), what type they are and how deep they go into the brick.  All these factors will have a bearing on whether your plan will work.

As is always the case when queries like this come up you have to realise that any assessment of the weight-carrying ability of any type of project is going to come down to a seat-of-the-pants assessment, so no concrete answers of any kind are possible AND those assessments are based on the variables. You haven't told us nearly enough about how this is constructed for even the most basic guess — there appear to be scant screws, we don't know what type or length, whether you drilled pilots, and very importantly we don't even know if you glued and if so how consistently and well.

Now a FWIW. While I'm a firm believer that thinner material can actually be good enough for many applications, I'd never have used 9mm ply here given the dimensions.... unless it was intended only to hold duvets (lightweight comforters) or down pillows. Additionally, I'd have attached it to all available surfaces, especially the ceiling.

I added some more information
